# $\sum\left(\frac{ n^2 + 1}{n^2 +n + 1}\right)^{n^2} $ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

The original question is to show that $\;\sum\left(\dfrac{ n^2 + 1}{n^2 +n + 1}\right)^{n^2} $ either converges or diverges.

I know it diverges but I'm having difficulty arriving at something useful for $  a_n $.

Here's what I did:
$  a_n = \left(\dfrac{ n^2 + 1}{n^2 +n + 1}\right)^{n^2} \geq\left( \dfrac{ n^2 + 1}{n^2 +2n + 1}\right)^{n^2}  \geq\left( \dfrac{ n^2 - 1}{n^2 +2n + 1}\right)^{n^2} = \left(\dfrac{(n-1)(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n^2}  = \left(\dfrac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} = \left( 1 - \dfrac{2}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} $

Do you have idea how to continue from here? ( my idea was to arrive to some expression that goes to infinity and deduce by the comparison test that $ a_n $ diverges ). I feel like something is right infront of my eyes but I can't see it.

**Edit**: The series converges. However, how do you propose I should continue from where I've left?

Comment: How do you know that it diverges ?

Comment: The general term is $\sim\left(\left(1-\dfrac1n\right)^n\right)^n$.

Comment: Did you type it in wrong? [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28+%5Cfrac%7B+n%5E2+%2B+1%7D%7Bn%5E2+%2Bn+%2B+1%7D+%29%5E%7Bn%5E2%7D+) shows it converges.

Comment: Oh man, I was looking at the $ -\infty $ limit all this time..., My friend told me this series diverges so I was further swayed by his claim. You are right, the series converges, but how do you propose I continue from where I left?

Comment: Since the series converges, you don't want to bound it from below, but from above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That series converges. If $n>1$, you have$$\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}\right)^{n^2}=\left(1-\frac n{n^2+n+1}\right)^{n^2}\leqslant\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{n^2}.$$But $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^n=\exp\left(-\frac12\right)$. Therefore, if you take some $c\in\left(\exp\left(-\frac12\right),1\right)$, you have $\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^n\leqslant c$ if $n\gg1$, and so $\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{n^2}\leqslant c^n$ if $n\gg1$.

Comment: Are you using root test?

Comment: That's a way of looking at it, but in my head I was using the comparison test.

Comment: Just a quick question on the notation, but is there an actual definition for what $n\gg 1$ means, or is it just an intuitive "n is much larger then 1"?

Comment: I think he means that $ \left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^n\leqslant c  $ from some index $ N \in \mathbb{N} $. that is what the  $ n\gg1 $ means.

Comment: The notation $n\gg1$ means that $n$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: What does $ c\in\left(\exp\left(-\frac12\right),1\right) $ mean? ( I don't think you meant ordered pair ), did you meant to write $ c\in  \{  \exp\left(-\frac12\right),1 \} $?

Comment: The expression $(a,b)$ means the interval $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a<x<b\}$. In particular$$\left(\exp\left(-\frac12\right),1\right)=\left\{x\in\Bbb R\,\middle|\,\exp\left(-\frac12\right)<x<1\right\}.$$So $x\in\left(\exp\left(-\frac12\right),1\right)$ means that $\exp\left(-\frac12\right)<c<1$.

Comment: @hazelnut_116: Just as a side note, we can also define the closed interval $[a,b]$ as $\{x\in\mathbb R:\,a\leq x\leq b \}$. Likewise, we can define the semiopen interval $(a,b] $ as $\{x\in\mathbb R:\,a<x\leq b \}$. You can see the pattern and define $[a,b) $ similarly.

Answer (score 1):

$n^{2} \ln (1-\frac  n {n^{2}+n+1}) \leq  \frac 1  2 (-n^{2})\frac  n {n^{2}+n+1} $ as for $n$ sufficiently large and $\sum e^{-n} <\infty$. Hence the series is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

You need not use any test to find that it converges, just application of standard limits will do, as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{ n^2 + 1}{n^2 +n + 1}\right)^{n^2}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n +1 + \frac1n}\right)^{n+1+\frac1n}\right]^\frac{n^2}{n+1+\frac1n}\\
&=0
\end{align}
This is because the inner limit is $\frac1e<1$ because $(1-\frac{1}{x})^x\xrightarrow{x\to\infty}\frac1e$ and the outer exponent goes to infinity.

Comment: So you are using limit arithmetic?

Comment: Yes @hazelnut_116, we have to use it in order to talk about convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the root test:

$$\sqrt[\Large n]{\left( \frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1} \right)^{n^2}} = \left( \frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1} \right)^{n} = \left[\left( 1-\frac{n}{n^2+n+1} \right)^{-\frac{n^2+n+1}{n}}\right]^{\frac{-n^2}{n^2+n+1}}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} e^{-1} < 1,$$

and therefore the series converges.

We used:

1. $\left( 1-\frac{n}{n^2+n+1} \right)^{-\frac{n^2+n+1}{n}}\to e$, because $\frac{n}{n^2+n+1}\to 0,$
2. $\frac{-n^2}{n^2+n+1}\to -1.$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\left(\frac{ n^2 + 1}{n^2 +n + 1}\right)^{n^2}\implies \log(a_n)=n^2\log\left(\frac{ n^2 + 1}{n^2 +n + 1}\right)$$
For large $n$
$$\log(a_n)=-n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{3 n}-\frac{3}{4 n^2}-\frac{1}{5
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Repeat it for $a_{n+1}$ to obtain
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=-1-\frac{2}{3 n^2}+\frac{13}{6 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=\frac 1e \left(1-\frac{2}{3 n^2}+\frac{13}{6 n^3} \right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ So, it converges.

Now, if you make
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty a_n$$
$$\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty a_n\sim \sum_{n=p+1}^\infty e^{\frac{1}{2}-n}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}-p}}{e-1}$$

If you make $p=4$, the approximation gives
$$\frac{31179700687749571657625354575093}{15170464778704564632455243642733}+\frac{1}{(e-
   1) e^{7/2}}\sim 2.072864$$ while the "excat" result is $2.074636$.